# Which thermistor or temperature sensors are less power draining?

Tags: low-power, thermistor

I am trying to build a low-power system. One of the system parts is a Temperature sensing circuit (0 <T<60 C).
Since I am have limited power (~500 uA 3V). I was lost as to which approach is the best in terms of less power consumption.

[high Accuracy and fast sampling are not necessary]

Types I am looking at:

- NTC Thermistor
- PTC Thermistor
- Digital sensor

Which one have usually better for low power application? and do you recommend a certain model?

Comment: Recommendations for certain models are discouraged on this stack exchange.  This may be an XY question -- if fast sampling isn't an issue, just about any sensor that's turned off most of the time may be a good choice.

Comment: What do you want do do with the measurement? I mean, if you read an NTC with digital electronics, this would turn into a digital sensor. So it wouldn't make much sense to compare NTC/PTC with a "digital sensor".

Comment: JFYI: a 100k NTC/PTC corresponds to ~30uA at 3V

Comment: @SimSon Thank you.

Comment: If you can find an NTC and a PTC with similar resistance, those two as a potential divider would give you the best of several worlds, except cost of course. Low quiescent current at any temperature, and wide voltage swing at the mid point.

Comment: You had three good answers on the duplicate question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to operate a lower power thermistor power circuit?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/552360/how-to-operate-a-lower-power-thermistor-power-circuit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various way to approach the problem… an NTC/PTC has obviously as load its value at the temperature of interest (usually around 10kohms but even more depending on the model)

Active temperature sensors vary wildly: the almost overused LM35 needs about 100µA to work and gives an analog voltage, the TMP05 has a 600µA active mode but can be put in standby at some 10µA (output is a pulse duration by the way).

And now the most important trick of all: just *power off* the sensor when you don't need it. Even a PT100 RTD (which is a 100 ohm resistor, more or less) consume almost no power if you power it up only, say, every 5 seconds (depending on the application)